# New command for AWS CLI v2 to replace `aws ecr get-login` of AWS CLI v1

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, flask, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

Encouraged by DockerCon 2020, I'm tackling again getting a flask app running on AWS EC2, but this time I don't want to touch the AWS dashboard. I'd like to stay entirely on the command line (osx terminal).

This [fine tutorial](https://linuxacademy.com/blog/linux-academy/deploying-a-containerized-flask-application-with-aws-ecs-and-docker/) describes how to build an image and run it on AWS ECR, apparently itself ultimately running behind the scenes on an EC2 instance.

I am guessing that the beginning of the translation to AWS CLI v2 of

```
v1: aws ecr get-login --region us-east-1 --no-include-email
```

is

```
v2: aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1
```

The v1 command apparently produced a string properly formatted for subsequent running. (Good riddance, cutting and pasting would not yield a reliable or a customizable CLI.)

The v2 replacement produces a long password for a subsequent command.

Which command(s) in v2 fully replace v1's `aws ecr get-login`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the documentation this can be [replaced](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cliv2-migration.html#cliv2-migration-ecr-get-login) by running

```
aws ecr get-login-password | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin MY-REGISTRY-URL
```

Regarding the `--no-include-email` the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/get-login.html) states the following

> You must specify --no-include-email if you're using Docker version 17.06 or later. The default behavior is to include the '-e' flag in the 'docker login' output.

Comment: Thanks for the link (in addition to the answer). Moral of the story: if googling for the specific (`aws ecr get-login invalid choice`, `aws cli v2 ecr get-login`) fails, try searching instead for the general (`aws 1 2 changes`), which will produce the needed reference at the first result.